# How to develop Google App Engine backend using Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add Google App Engine functionality to my Android App.  I am using Android Studio, and have had a look at [Brad Abrams Google I/O talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=lmv1dTnhLH4) and [another tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html), but Android Studio seems to have moved on from where it was at this time last year, and the Google Cloud Endpoints functionality has been removed.  I can see at GitHub that the menu option "Generate App Engine Backend" was removed from Android Studio and replaced with "New App Engine Gradle Module".

Are there any options to allow me to generate the App Engine Backend like in those examples from Android Studio, or do I need to use Eclipse to do this?

Comment: I'm working on the same issue right now.  Currently you need to use the Google Cloud Tools-New App Engine Gradle Module-APp Engine Backend with GCM.  This will give you the same starting point as Eclipse and you can modify the endpoints.  I'm stuck incorporating it into a module though, I imagine it has something to do with Gradle Dependencies but I haven't nailed it down yet.  Might try to bump this for Commonsware, not sure if he looks at AS though.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not use GAE, so I cannot answer your question.

Comment: It turns out the old flow, as described in those sessions, was prone to too many errors because it interacted with too many components. When you add a new App Engine Gradle Module you have to do connect to your Android module by following the instructions on http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html and  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/blob/master/GcmEndpoints/README.md

Answer (score 9):

This answer is based on AndroidStudio 0.8.3.

1. Select the top most level of your project, right click **New > Module** and select **App Engine Java Endpoints**
2. set the name for your module, such as **mymodule**
3. Your **build.gradle** file will now have a new line:

   `compile project(path: ':mymodule', configuration: 'android-endpoints')`
4. Now you will want to open **mymodule/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml** and replace myApplicationID with your **appengine PROJECT ID** which you can get from [cloud.google.com/console](http://cloud.google.com/console)
5. You can now either change the configuration to myModule (toolbar) and press run. It will launch a local server, or you can select **Gradle** on the upper right hand side of the window and look for **:mymodule** and click on **appengineUpdate** or **appengineUpdateAll**.

[More detail here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/06/new-ways-to-connect-your-app-to-the-cloud-android-studio.html) and [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates)