# App engine cloud endpoints backend and android in the same maven project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, maven, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

Can I create app engine cloud endpoints backend project for my android application, so that I can manage the  server and client library code in the same maven project?

Currently I have an android project in android studio, but I want to add a cloud endpoints backend to it. Dont want to manage 2 separate projects in git for these.

Comment: Poosibly this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820678/how-to-develop-google-app-engine-backend-using-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the cloud backend using Android Studio itself. It is quiet straightforward!You need to add App Engine first to your package and then generate end points. I have tried it and it works perfectly fine.[image]

Comment: thanks G3M, does this allow to deploy to app-engine from the same project?

Comment: this seems to be not a maven project, which means I can't use push-to-deploy in app-engine?